# Materializecss Autocomplete chips with custom data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, materialize

I'm using materializecss chips with autocomplete option and setting the autocomplete data using an ajax. The documentation shows setting basic tags using the following syntax:

```
$('.chips-autocomplete').chips({
    autocompleteOptions: {
      data: {
        'Apple': null,
        'Microsoft': null,
        'Google': null
      },
      limit: Infinity,
      minLength: 1
    }
  });
```

However when I actually want to use these tags, I want some additional data apart from just the name of the tag (id, for eg.) so that I can do `PATCH` requests with the `id` field. I am currently unable to achieve this.

If I do this:

```
autocompleteOptions: {
      data: {
        'golang': {
          tag: 'golang',
          id: 1
        },
        'docker': {
          tag: 'docker',
          id: 2
        },
        'kubernetes': {
          tag: 'kubernetes',
          id: 3
        }
      },
      minLength: 2
    },
```

My autocomplete field does not render properly:
[image]

also, the `onChipAdd` callback function does not receive the chip with full data and only looks like:

```
{
  tag: 'golang'
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this in materializecss?

Answer (score 11):

There's no direct method. You need to modify the library. The autocomplete callback always is replaced.

Assuming you are using [Materialize v1.0.0](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.js) and your autocomplete data object,

Modify the next lines:

6765 => Modify Autocomplete callback for new object

```
this.options.onAutocomplete.call(this, text); //ORIGINAL
//Replace with this
this.options.onAutocomplete.call(this, {text: text, id: parseInt(el[0].dataset.tagId)});  //CUSTOM
```

6792 => Modify the Entry Object for Autocomplete data

```
var entry = {
    data: data[key],
    key: key
};
//Replace with this
var entry = {
    data: data[key].img,
    key: data[key].tag, 
    id: data[key].id
};
```

6814 => Render Autocomplete dropdown with modified list items

```
var $autocompleteOption = $("<li></li>"); //ORIGINAL
//Replace with this
var $autocompleteOption = $("<li data-tag-id="+_entry.id+"></li>"); //CUSTOM
```

7890 => Setup Autocomplete callback for chips

```
_this46.addChip({
    tag: val
});
//Replace with this
_this46.addChip({
    id: val.id,
    tag: val.text,
});
```

Done!

I had the same trouble and this is how I solved it. I used the "data-tag-id" attribute of the `<li>` to pass the ID of my tags. When you get the data from the chips, you will have the tag property and the id property.

PD: If you want to show autocomplete with image preview, you need to set autocomplete data object like this:

```
data:{ 'key':{tag:'key', img:'url/to/image.png', id: 2} }
```

I hope I've helped :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Perhaps consider renaming `img` to `image` to keep it consistent with the library.

Answer (score 0):

The `M.Chips.autocomplete` is an [autocomplete object](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html)  which has `updateData` method.
You can use:

```
`let options =  {
            placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
            autocompleteOptions: {
                data: {},
                limit: Infinity,
                minLength: 1
            }
        }
let instances = M.Chips.init(elems, options);
let myChip = instances[0]

// Call server 
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'My/Url';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
            if (Http.status == 200 && Http.readyState == 4) {
                let data = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
                // assume that data has the following syntax
                // {
                //    "Apple": null,
                //    "Microsoft": null,
                //    "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
                //  }
                myChip.autocomplete.updateData(data);                    
            }
        }`
```